# Theme Advanced Styles in Visual Editor and Paragraphs

Tags: themes, wysiwyg, visual-editor

After i add these codes to functions.php:

```
add_editor_style();

function childtheme_mce_btns2($orig) {
return array('formatselect','styleselect', 'underline', 'justifyfull', 'forecolor', '|', 'pastetext', 'pasteword', 'removeformat', '|', 'media', 'charmap', '|', 'outdent', 'indent', '|', 'undo', 'redo', 'wp_help' );
}
add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', 'childtheme_mce_btns2', 999 );

function childtheme_tiny_mce_before_init( $init_array ) {
$init_array['theme_advanced_styles'] = "box note=box_note;box info=box_info;box warning=box_warning;box download=box_download";
return $init_array;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'childtheme_tiny_mce_before_init' );
```

I had a style drop down menu in Wordpress Visual Editor with "box note,box info,box warning,box download" options. I created editor-style.css so i got css support for those classes in visual editor.

If i select "box note" style example, wordpress putting it as `<p class="box_note"></p>` Problem is when i push enter button for line breaking, wordpress putting `<p></p>` automatically.

Basically how can i change those styles using `<div> <span>` or anything except `<p>`?

**Update:**
I create some screenshots for you. This is when i select style from style list:
http://www.unsalkorkmaz.com/sorun/sorun1.jpg
This is when i push enter button for line breaking:
http://www.unsalkorkmaz.com/sorun/sorun2.jpg
Wordpress basically creating different `<p>`

I tried;

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('the_content', 'convert_smilies');
remove_filter('the_content', 'convert_chars');
```

before i create this question but its not the solution seems.

**Update 2:**
Well.. I tried shift+enter to line-break and it works! So i dont know what is difference with enter vs shift+enter in TinyMCE but i want shift+enter function as default of enter button.

Comment: and.. i found interesting solution in there: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=3360 last msg

Comment: This probably is a bug or missing feature in wordpress. From what I write I have the feeling that the editor is just not working in a way you expect it. Probably it's worth to report this to the wordpress hackers list or to open a ticket in trac.

Comment: i opened a ticket: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15526 they are working on tinymce these days i see, maybe they will add this too

Comment: shift+enter and enter is not specific for this editor. It is also that way e.g. in ms word, excel, outlook, livewriter, etc... etc... it is a convention. the difference between a linefeed and a carriage return... this makes the difference. People even requested this change for microsoft word... : http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Word/microsoft.public.word.conversions/2004-06/0182.html see also : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return ....

Comment: see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_return and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_return and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRLF

Comment: Now that you found shift+enter, let me tell you that's just the normal use of the WYSIWYG editor. In HTML view, the ENTER works as you like it. So probably learn the tools first - WYSIWYG is most often a lie, and it looks to me a bit that you expect too much from a broken concept - not to say that especially in worpdress the visual editor has massive problems with line-breaking and paragraph switches since ages. So don't expect too much from it in a general sense as well. It's been reported numerous times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always want `<br/>` instead of `<p>` for newlines you can [change the TinyMCE configuration](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aFAQ#TinyMCE_produce_P_elements_on_enter.2Freturn_instead_of_BR_elements.3F):

```
forced_root_block: false,
force_br_newlines: true,
force_p_newlines : false,
```

I think you cannot do this based on the context (use `<br/>` when in `class="box_note"`, `<p>` otherwise), but it is an interesting question for [the TinyMCE forum](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/). <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is indeed the standard way to differentiate between paragraph and line endings.

Comment: i found those too but when i try to add these as "wordpress" way with filters without editing core, they just didnt work.. can you write wordpress code working? maybe i can found what i am doing wrong

Comment: basically problem was wordpress adding "" to false/true sections

Comment: @Ünsal: Indeed, stupid WordPress does not accept non-string values. [Unless you trick it.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3882/can-i-add-a-custom-format-to-the-format-option-in-the-text-panel/3884#3884)

Comment: i accept your answer mate. thanks a lot. esspecially your comment link answer is the trick

Comment: @Ünsal: Good news: in WP 3.1 boolean values can pass without being wrapped in quotes, because of [an extra check when writing the JS config variable](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/16090/trunk/wp-admin/includes/post.php).

Answer (score 0):

Is this your quesion:

1. http://www.orphicpixel.com/common-wordpress-annoyance/
2. [Line breaks not showing up properly](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3469/line-breaks-not-showing-up-properly)
3. [How can I improve the line break handling in the WYSIWYG editor?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/506/how-can-i-improve-the-line-break-handling-in-the-wysiwyg-editor)
4. [Why is WordPress WYSIWYMG and how do I make it WYSIWYG?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3732/why-is-wordpress-wysiwymg-and-how-do-i-make-it-wysiwyg)

?

Comment: i updated question.. i am talking about TinyMce live edit, those problems are "after" save post seems. Thanks for help btw :)

Comment: And..  i tried Tiny MCE Advanced with "Stop Removing the <p>and <br/> tags when saving and show them in the HTML editor"

Comment: and.. update 2: I tried shift+enter to line-break and it works! So i dont know what is difference with enter vs shift+enter in TinyMCE but i want shift+enter function as default of enter button.

Comment: The problem is that the content replacement is hard-coded into the editor javascript, when you switch editor modes(visual/html) you envoke a replacement script that runs over the content, which can't account for your custom styles..