# Stop certain classes showing up in TinyMCE Advanced Style dropdown

Tags: editor, tinymce

I'm using the TinyMCE Advanced plugin so that I can add my own custom styles to the Style dropdown in the Visual Editor. However, I don't want some of the styles that are included in the style.css file to be listed there, as they are 'internal' classes (for aligning pictures etc).

Is there a way to stop these classes being shown in the dropdown? Either by changing the TinyMCE Advanced configuration, or by editing the CSS file in a certain way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for - put this code into your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'yourprefix_tiny_mce_before_init' );
function yourprefix_tiny_mce_before_init( $init_array ) {

    // filter styles:
    $init_array['theme_advanced_styles'] = "your_style=your_class";

    // filter formats:
    $init_array['theme_advanced_blockformats'] = "p,h3,h4,h5";

    return $init_array;
}
```

This way the only style that will be displayed is `your_style`.

The 3rd line is taking care of tinymce formats - might be useful too.

See [Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/tiny_mce_before_init](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/tiny_mce_before_init)  for more informations and examples.

Comment: Great! Is there documentation for these options anywhere? For example, how would I let multiple styles through?

Comment: use semicolon:
$init_array['theme_advanced_styles'] = "your_style=your_class;another_class=your_class2";

google 'tiny_mce_before_init' for more .)

Comment: related: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4349/theme-advanced-styles-in-visual-editor-and-paragraphs