# Is there a plugin to show the code tag button on the visual editor?

Tags: plugins, visual-editor

I write a programming blog, so sometimes I just have to write a word to represent a `command` or `function` which I like writing between the code tags. (See, what I just did there).

So, just like StackExchange has the "code" button, is there a plugin to add this button to the visual editor? I know I got it on the HTML editor, but I rarely use it.

I was thinking of writing a plugin for this, but just in case I'm asking first in case anyone knows of a plugin doing this already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be a few people scratching this itch over at the TinyMCE sourceforge tracker. http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=103281&atid=738747

This looks promising.. "CodeExtras adds `<var> and <code>` markup buttons - ID: 2904557"
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2904557&group_id=103281&atid=738747

Comment: You could also add the code tag to the blockformats dropdown like in the example here.   http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration:theme_advanced_blockformats

Comment: It is such a small edit, that it could be overkill to search for a plugin to do this. Just add the `<code>` tag to [the blockformats dropdown](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6678/stop-certain-classes-showing-up-in-tinymce-advanced-style-dropdown/6681#6681) and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this code, but I think it should work:

```
add_filter('mce_buttons','rw_mce_buttons');
function rw_mce_buttons($mce_buttons) {
    $mce_buttons[] = 'code';

    return $mce_buttons;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Could be that TinyMCE no longer has this button?

Answer (score 0):

You can press `Shift+Alt+X` when you have hovered the text.

All Wordpress Editor keyboard shortcuts:
https://danigeorgiev.com/wordpress-editor-tinymce-keyboard-shortcuts/